# How do you automate bulk SMS/phone number verification without buying SIM cards?

Tags: sms, verification, phone-number, bulk

I came along these account stores, that sell Google accounts, Twitter accounts, etc. All of them are PVA - phone verified. E.g. 1000 phone verified Gmail accounts can cost ~260$. And they have tens of thousands of them in stock.

I was wondering, how do you automate SMS verification in such amount? I know account creation process can be automated using simple browser automation (e.g. Selenium), but no idea about SMS.

Are there any APIs for very short term phone number renting? Twilio charges 1$ per phone number.

Comment: hey did you ever figure this out? I imagine its a good way to make money so most people don't share it x)

Answer (score 0):

you can google and contact some of the bulksms providers who can give you 2FA solution or OTP API

Comment: aren't these bulksms providers letting you *send* bulk sms, when in this case you need to *receive* bulk sms into many different phone numbers? E.g. 1k accounts = 1k numbers needed

Comment: hey did you figure it out?